How to set the principal name of a Spring Security OAuth2AuthorizedClient using access token response?
I am currently playing around with Spring Security 6's OAuth2 Client in Spring Boot 3.
I am using an authorization_code grant which is exchanged for an access token using the following security config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).oauth2Client(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .authorizationCodeGrant(codeGrant -> codeGrant
                                .accessTokenResponseClient(new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient())))
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}

The token response of the OAuth2 provider I am using is:
(This is an example, provided by the provider)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
    "refresh_expires_in": 7776000
    "membership_id":"4352344"
}

My issue is that I need the principal name for the associated OAuth2AuthorizedClient to match the membership_id provided in the token response. However, I have no idea how to do this.
Any help is much appreciated.

Spring has this builtin to its configuration feature.
You can either added a userInfoUri and a userNameAttributeName to the application.yml file or you can add it via the ClientRegistration Builder
return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("bungie")
                .clientId("id")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .authorizationUri("https://www.bungie.net/en/OAuth/Authorize")
                .tokenUri("https://www.bungie.net/platform/app/oauth/token/")
                .userInfoUri("https://www.bungie.net/Platform/User/GetMembershipsForCurrentUser/")
                .userNameAttributeName("primaryMembershipId")
                .clientName("bungie")
                .redirectUri("redirect")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .build();

Please note that for using this with the Bungie OAuth2 Service you have to customize the DefaultOAuth2UserService and the DefaultOAuth2UserRequestEntityConverter to support proper parsing and for adding the X-API-Key to the user info request
